# Did the Humans find out about Gaius Baltar's role in the sabotage of the fleet?

Tags: battlestar-galactica

In the new Battlestar Galacticia it is shown that the Cylons were able to wipe out the Colonial Fleet using backdoors in their defence software.
These backdoors got in through some deal Gaius made with Caprica Six, although at the time he did not know that she was a Cylon.

We the viewers find this out early (I think it's in one of the first episodes of the miniseries) but does anyone in the Fleet ever find out? Either from Gaius letting it slip or from Caprica Six/another Cylon letting on?

Comment: I'm sure they did (or at least it was strongly suspected) but I can't remember how. Maybe in his trial after the New Caprica saga?

Comment: I know there was a trial for what happened no New Caprica but if the Humans did find out about his role in the genocide then I cannot believe that he would have made it to the end of the series.

Comment: Reality check: Baltar's "guilt" is 99% survivor's guilt, i.e. He feels horrible for what happened.  His only real crime was sharing his security access with an unvetted person, whilst working for a huge military for whom no enemies had been seen in living memory (except human minorities), making it a pointless government entitlement scheme at best, on a mission with no purpose, which was more likely to be misused for thuggery.  2004 Baltar is not a villain, but is merely sitting in a villain's seat: 1978 Baltar.

Answer (score 7):

## No, nearly all the characters do not find out, BUT an injured, nearly dying, and drug-induced Baltar confesses to [Laura Roslin](https://en.battlestarwikiclone.org/wiki/Laura_Roslin) while they were visiting the basestar to ask the hybrid questions about the Opera House in the season four episode, *The Hub*.

> On the basestar, Roslin unsuccessfully attempts to communicate with
> the Hybrid, only gleaming the message to "protect the child." During
> the Battle of the Resurrection Hub, Roslin attempts to administer
> first aid to a severely injured Baltar, injecting him with morpha. **As
> a result of the drugs, Baltar admits to Roslin that he unintentionally
> gave the Cylons the access codes to the Colonial Defense Mainframe,
> resulting in the attack on the Colonies. Roslin immediately stops
> administering aid and sits idly by while Baltar bleeds**. However,
> another vision of Elosha convinces her that she cannot lose her
> humanity. Realizing this, Roslin helps stabilize Baltar and never
> pursues his role in the attack further. When Adama finds the missing
> basestar and reunites with Roslin, she tells him that she loves him

He never specifically tells her it was Caprica Six, but he does tell how he unintentionally gave the Cylons the access codes. Roslin almost lets Baltar bleed out and die as a result, until she has a vision with Elosha who reminds her the importance of her own humanity. Roslin never reveals this truth to anyone.

Comment: As a result it’s safe to say Roslyn was the only human who knew the truth and it died with her on Earth.

Comment: @MissouriSpartan true, but I am curious to see "when" Sam Esmail's spin-off will take place and/or if it has potential to more ardently tie-in this story at all.

Comment: I’m behind the times!!! There’s a spin off coming?!

Comment: Ya! It could take place at any time or be a sidequel (details are scarce), but it was just announced for NBC's new streaming service "Peacock" : https://www.syfy.com/syfywire/new-battlestar-galactica-series-wont-be-a-reboot

Comment: ^<>^  WOOOOT!!! That’s the stuff! I was glued to my TV each Saturday night a new BSG episode aired.

Comment: Me too! And I loved all of the other spin-offs and am so sad neither really made it.

Comment: Caprica was getting promising....

Comment: I instantly feel in love with Coker on Blood and Chrome too. It was Saul and Anders mixed together!

Answer (score 4):

## No

Although Baltar is put on trial it was for "collaborating" with the Cylons on New Caprica.

His involvement in the original attack is referenced but under interrogation he is unspecific in what his actually role and culpability was.

[**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaius_Baltar)

> Baltar is subjected to a hallucinogen-based interrogation by Admiral Adama about any involvement with the Cylons. Baltar admits his unwitting complicity in the original Cylon attack on the Colonies, though without any specifics.